# Given a target aspect ratio, how to crop into image, framing around a found face

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have 800x800 portrait image and want to crop into it, finding the face and "framing it" in the centre, while maintaining a 3:4 aspect ratio (outline select box).

So I almost need to calculate some kind of "centre point" of the calculated `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` and crop into that point (red dots).

[image]

I believe I'm someway off reaching this goal as my python isn't particularly good - here's what I have so far:

```
cropped_face_image = numpy.array(PIL.Image.open(BytesIO(image.content)))[
    top:bottom, left:right
]
pil_image = PIL.Image.fromarray(cropped_face_image)
pil_image.show()
```

This just hard-crops the face from the image.

Comment: are you looking for [`Image.crop()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop)?

Comment: I am asking, given `top, bottom, left, and right` values of where the face is in the 800x800 image, how do I frame the face while maintaining a 3:4 crop

Comment: What does "frame the face" mean? I thought what you are doing is already "frame the face".

Comment: so you have top, bottom, left, and right of the face itself which may not be 3:4 aspect ratio, and you want to adjust those values to make it 3:4 aspect?

Comment: the 800x800 image doesn't just contain the face. cropping by the known values `top, bottom, left, and right` hard crops around the face. These are generated by a face detection function. I want to crop into the 800x800 image with a 3:4 aspect ratio, centring to those known points

Comment: `I almost need to calculate some kind of "centre point"` yup. that's the first step. then decide if you want the new crop to be sized based on the width or the height and scale the other dimension by your chosen ratio (3:4). just a little bit of algebra...

Comment: @Aaron please have a shot at an answer if you think you'd be able to help  I'm not sure how I would find that centre point

Comment: `(top + bottom) / 2` and `(left + right) / 2`?

Comment: So you have the entire grey image and the red points, but you want to get the dotted box?

Comment: @MarkSetchell exactly!

Comment: Ok, so how do you determine either the width or the height of the dotted box? You have to know one or the other because you can just say *"w and h are in the ratio 4:3"* because that allows them to be 4 and 3 pixels or 8 and 6 pixels or many other things.

Comment: Maybe you say the width of the dotted box should be 2x the width of the face and the height is then in the ratio to that?

Comment: Exactly, something dynamic @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('FlKyDm.png.jpeg')
top, bottom, left, right = 95, 177 , 70, 150

# Calculate centre of face and box
centreX, centreY = int((left+right)/2), int((top+bottom)/2)

# Calculate face width
faceW = right - left

# Calculate half width of box and half height of box
boxHalfW = faceW
boxHalfH = int((boxHalfW * 4) / 3)

# Crop accordingly
res = im.crop((centreX-boxHalfW, centreY-boxHalfH, centreX+boxHalfW, centreY+boxHalfH))
res.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Absolute fire! Cheers Mark